# Can I use past perfect IF with future or present tense?

Tags: grammar

Are these correct and what's the difference?

The fact is that **if** someone **has** bamboozled a person in the past, **then** they are bound to do it again.

The fact is that **if** someone **had** bamboozled a person in the past, **then** they are bound to do it again.

Comment: You second version has an invalid mixture of tenses. It should be *...then they **would be** bound to do it again*. It's very difficult to come up with a context where it would make sense to end with *...then they **were** bound to do it again*, but syntactically speaking that version would also be fine. And *...then they **would have been** bound to do it again* is also "valid", but it's almost impossible to imagine a context where anyone would want to say that.

Comment: Good answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You[r] second version has an invalid mixture of tenses. It should be *...then they **would be** bound to do it again*.
>
> It's very difficult to come up with a context where it would make sense to end with ...*then they **were** bound to do it again*, but syntactically speaking that version would also be fine. And ...*then they **would have been bound** to do it again* is also "valid", but it's almost impossible to imagine a context where anyone would want to say that.
> @FumbleFingers [[link]](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/316143/can-i-use-past-perfect-if-with-future-or-present-tense#comment593281_316143)